# MATLAB for loop plotting with varying parameter

Tags: matlab

I want to plot this

```
f(x)=3*(1-x)+7*x+8.314*T((1-x)*(lnx)+x*(lnx))+20*x(1-x)
```

with `T` varying from `0` to `2000` with interval of `100`{A total of 20 graphs all in the same}

Give a very basic code involving for loop and plot function.
PS : I am a beginer in `MATLAB`

Comment: Do you mean 20 points, instead of 20 graphs?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Matlab. :) Here's how we would do this without the loop:

```
% Define your function in terms of x and T
% Note that we use .* instead of * - this does a pairwise multiply
%  instead of a matrix or vector multiply
f = @(x,T) 3*(1-x)+7*x+8.314*T.*((1-x).*log(x)+x.*log(x))+20*x.*(1-x);

% Set your domain
x = linspace(0, 10, 101);
T = (0:100:2000);

% Compute your function for all values of x and T
tmp = bsxfun(f, x, T');

% Plot your output, all at the same time
plot(x, tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f=@(x,T) 3*(1-x)+7*x+8.314*T*((1-x).*log(x)+x.*log(x))+20*x.*(1-x);
T=0:100:2000;
x=linspace(0,10,100);
for i=1:length(T)
    plot(x,f(x,T(i)));
    hold on;
end
```